# Recycler view is not displaying data from firebase using an array list

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

i am retrieve data from a firebase database using an array list which then fills a recycler [my firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOgI5.jpg) View. the data is not displaying however in the recycler View.

My Model class here

```
public class ModelCategory {
String id,category,uid;
long timestamp;

public ModelCategory() {
}

public ModelCategory(String id, String category, String uid, long timestamp) {
    this.id=id;
    this.category =category;
    this.uid=uid;
    this.timestamp=timestamp;

}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public long getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
```

Class used to load recycler view

```
 private void loadCategories() {
    
    categoryArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
   
    DatabaseReference reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("category");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            categoryArrayList.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                ModelCategory category =  ds.getValue(ModelCategory.class);


                categoryArrayList.add(category);
            }

            adapterCategory= new AdapterCategory(DashboardAdminActivity.this,categoryArrayList);
            binding.categoriesRvk.setAdapter(adapterCategory);

        }
```

The load category method is in Main activity.

My adapter

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HolderCategory holder, int position) {
    //get data
    ModelCategory model= categoryArrayList.get(position);
    String id= model.getId();
    String uid= model.getUid();
    String category= model.getCategory();
    long timestamp= model.getTimestamp();

    //set data
    holder.categoryTv.setText(category);


    //handle delete btn click
    holder.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "deleted "+category, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

this is the adapter that i am using

Comment: Show us the code that you are using to display the data in the RecyclerView, not just the model class.

Comment: @AlexMamo added adapter and code used to display the data in The Rv.

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your screenshot, it's `categories` and **not** `category`. So please change:

```
DatabaseReference reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("category");
```

Into:

```
DatabaseReference reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("categories");
```

Comment: changed it but still not working

Comment: "still not working" doesn't provide enough information so I can further help. What exactly didn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: There is no error shown anywhere.  I can add the data to but the recyclers view is not getting embedded to the view.

Comment: Are you sure isn't something related to the UI?

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.